# Is Cron the right option for this?

Tags: cron

I am trying to create a script that watches my college time table and registers them for a class when it is open. Kind of like an Ebay auction sniper. I was wondering if cron is the right tool for this. I need to be able to run the script for every user. The user will enter their username and password and the script will query the timetable.

Looking for some advice on if cron is the tool or if there are other tools out there.

Answer (score 1):

`cron` runs a particular program or script at a specified time.  For example, if you wanted a report compiled and e-mailed every day at 2 a.m., that would be a `cron` job.

In this sense, `cron` has a timetable, but I am not sure that it is the sort of timetable of which you are thinking.

From a system-design perspective, the clean way to achieve the effect you want naturally would be to let the students' class requests join a queue, then to have the college's registrar's own computer take requests from the queue as seats became available.  However, I assume from your Ebay reference that this is not possible in your case.

Comment: I do not have access to the college's registrar. I am simply scarping the html every time I make a query to check the classes.

Comment: You did not ask whether scarping the registrar's html was a good idea, so pay me no mind if you like.  Of course, it probably won't work:  they'll shut you down if your script visits often enough to catch every open seat.

Comment: Then `cron` will do what you want, running your script every five minutes, or whatever.  For future reference, see also `at`, which is closely related to `cron`.